# jQuery modal will not display when I click button

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a modal window that pops up when you click the sign in button in the nav bar. I've made it so both the modal and it's page overlay are set with `'display: none'` in css. I've tried every method I could to get it to display on click and I just can't get it to work. I've tried `fadeIn()`. I've tried `.css()` to change it. I even tried making a special class with only 'display: none' and using `.removeClass()`. Nothing works!

This is a school assignment so I can't use jQuery UI. I'm not asking for it to be done for me. I just want a nudge in the right direction. Can someone help me? This is the code I've got right now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.overlay').removeClass('.displaynone');
        $('.modal').removeClass('.displaynone');
    });
});
```

Here is a JS Fiddle with the whole situation out there. The Log In button is supposed to bring up the overlay and the modal on top of it. I'd like for it to fade in, preferably with the modal having a second delay.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/duagdn8m/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/duagdn8m/5/
Just remove the . on the classname that you want to remove.

```
$('.overlay').removeClass('displaynone');
$('.modal').removeClass('displaynone');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `.` in the class names too. This is not needed. You don't need `.` notation here:

```
$('.overlay').removeClass('displaynone');
$('.modal').removeClass('displaynone');
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cnye843k/**

I would suggest giving an `absolute` as `position`ing for the login screen, to make it a modal. Or if you have not included the CSS, then fine.

Comment: I actually just figured this out right after I posted this. I can't believe that. I worked on this all of last night and couldn't get it to work. Then I post this and figure it out with no problem. Thanks though, I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the `.` in `removeClass('.displaynone');` and the `overlay` and `modal` are classes, not `ids`. so you need to update your css to `.overlay` and `.modal`.

also, its easier to set the `overlay` and `modal` to `display:none;` and then `fadeIn` the both like so:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.overlay, .modal').fadeIn(1000)
    });
});
```

This will give you the 1 second fade in.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/duagdn8m/6/)